# Simulating a click on a menu item in Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

It's fairly simple to simulate a button click in Robolectric:

```
Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_button);
someButton.performClick();
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing with a menu item. I create a menu in `Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu`, how can I simulate a click on one of its items?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
MenuItem item = new TestMenuItem() {
  public int getItemId() {
    return R.id.hello;
  }
};

activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity);
Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);

assertThat(shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName(), equalTo(HelloActivity_.class.getName()));
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It has become even easier, instead of creating the anonymous type, you can now use


    ``MenuItem item = new TestMenuItem(R.id.hello);``

Comment: Make sure to use `RoboMenuItem(id)` in Robolectric 3.0+.

Comment: Also in Roboelectric 3.0 it is Shadows.shadowOf(activity)

Answer (score 18):

In Robolectric 3.0+, you can use [`ShadowActivity.clickMenuItem(menuItemResId)`](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-3.0-rc2/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowActivity.java#L382):

```
        // Get shadow
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);

    // Click menu
    shadowActivity.clickMenuItem(R.id.settings_option_item);

    // Get intent
    Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Shadows.shadowOf(startedIntent);

// Make your assertion
assertThat(shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName(), equalTo(HelloActivity_.class.getName()));
```

Answer (score 12):

In robolectric 3.0+ the class is called `RoboMenuItem`

Comment: and then what? I'm guessing you mean that TestMenuItem became RoboMenuItem, but what about the rest of the code?

Answer (score 2):

You are already using Robolectric then why don't use `RoboMenuItem` ?

```
private MenuItem menuItemName = new RoboMenuItem(R.id.action_names);
private MenuItem menuItemStar = new RoboMenuItem(R.id.action_stars);
```

> add as many items as required.

```
@Test
public void onOptionItemSelectedTest() {
    activity.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItemStar);
    activity.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItemName);
}
```

**Make sure your activity is not null**

```
 @Before
public void setUp() {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class)
            .create(new Bundle())
            .saveInstanceState(new Bundle())
            .restoreInstanceState(new Bundle())
            .resume()
            .get();
}
```

**Robolectric version `4.3`**

Answer (score 1):

Using robolectric 2.4:

```
Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
MenuItem item = new TestMenuItem(R.id.settings_option_item);
activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Mockito if you'd like to cut down on the amount of overriding/abstract coding required.  Like this (in Kotlin):

```
val menuItem = mock(MenuItem::class.java)
`when`(menuItem.itemId).thenReturn(R.id.itemId)
activity.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
```